# React router Link importing issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-router, react-router-dom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhAdl.png)I have completely installed my react router and my project is build completely but the only issue is that when I imported this

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
```

Import in `App.js`
[image]

Import in `Navbar.js`
[image]

the `Link` is in light color in vs code compared to others that means that means it is not imported and thus I cannot replace anchor tag and href with Link to="".
Anyone can please help with the solution because without these I cannot continue further.

Comment: I don't see an issue with the code. Are there any actual errors or linting errors? The `Link` is a common component, so there shouldn't have been any way for you to install an incorrect version of `react-router-dom`. What exactly does "is in light color in vs code compared to others that means that means it is not imported" mean? Can you share a screenshot? Sometimes, depending on your theme, different object types/references are colored differently... it doesn't mean they weren't imported correctly.

Comment: is your react-router-dom version is 5 ?

Comment: yes 5.2.0 and react-dom is 18.2.0

Comment: Well, with those versions of RRD (v5.2.0) and React (v18), if you are rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component you'll have issues with the router/links. See my answer [here](/a/71833424/8690857) for issue and solution. This is separate from any issue you are reporting here.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot

Comment: From what I can tell that looks more like an unused import in the screenshot. Are you rendering a `Link` component anywhere there in the file? You can edit the post to include a complete [mcve] for that file.

Comment: I attached one more screenshot where I have shown that I have used the link component

Comment: Ok, you've imported the `Link` component into two different files. The import in `Navbar` is normal since it's actually rendering a `Link`. I think you've just an unused import in the `App.js` file.

Comment: Is there any correction that I need to do ?

Comment: Delete `App.js:13` since it seems you're not using that imported `Link` component in that file.

Comment: But I want to use that Link in react and the issue is that when I can keeping anchor tag and href the component gets loaded but it doesnt get loaded when I replace it with link

Comment: <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">{props.aboutText}</Link>

Comment: I added this and now its not loading the component but when i do so with the anchor tag then it dos

Comment: Added *what*? This would all probably be easier if you could add `App.js` to your post as a [mcve] so we can see what it's importing and rendering.

Comment: I added ss of App.js

Comment: The screenshot isn't the entire code though. All the screenshot shows is that you've imported `Link` and very likely are not using it. It's not an error and your code is probably transpiling and running, right? If you are not rendering `Link` anywhere in `App` then remove the import. If you are trying to render a `Link`, then please share a complete code example. If there are errors in the terminal or console, please include those.

Comment: Sir actually I am new to stackoverflow so I am not able to find how to upload complete code , can we connect somewhere where u r comfortable? Thank u for giving ur time by the way

Comment: It's the same as where you included the import example; create a code snippet using the three backtick characters and copy/paste the complete `App.js` code inside.

Comment: Ok so my issue is that I have removed the link from that router but the main problem is in the latest image that I am inserting right now in that image I gave a routing path for eg. about. But when I click on that about in the website the url changes to about but the component doesnt get loaded

Answer (score 0):

Close the Link tag in `Navbar.js`

in line 9 of `Navbar.js`

```
<Link className="navbar-brand" to="/"><Link>
```

and in line 16 of `Navbar.js`

```
<Link className="nav-link active" aria-current="page to="/"><Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Link** module imported in `App.js` is **not yet used**
that's why it is in light color.

***ProTip***: If you are not using **Link** module in `App.js`, just remove the import